# Trying to get banner inside of the header

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to get a banner with "slogan" and an image to appear inside the header area. When I write it out it appears below the header section, and I cannot figure out how to get it inside the header area.

I would also like to make it responsive. So I would like the "slogan" to move up and the image to move below the "slogan" when it reaches less than 768px

Thanks

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}


/* Header */

.header-image {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472376758045-62f519fc676d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8300925c51f6d651fa7cb9c41eaafb45&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2850&q=80');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 49em;
}

.header-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  height: 49em;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-left: .5em;
}

.nav-header {
  grid-column: 2;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* Banner */

.slogan,
.banner {
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-image {
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- HEADER -->

<header class="header-image">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <h1 class="logo">STARTUP NAME</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-header">
        <li class="navmenu">Services</li>
        <li class="navmenu">Pricing</li>
        <li class="navmenu">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>


<!-- BANNER -->


<section class="main-banner">
  <div class="banner-container">
    <h1 class="slogan banner">Some Cool Slogan</h1>
    <span class="slogan banner">A cool subtitle explaining said cool Slogan</span>
    <img class="banner-image banner" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532007271951-c487760934ae?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=f7ad947fb913065733cd1494ed95ef59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted the code to have a wrapper around the title and to have it at the center of the page. And added media query CSS to come one below the other in mobile

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}


/* Header */

.header-image {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472376758045-62f519fc676d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8300925c51f6d651fa7cb9c41eaafb45&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2850&q=80');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 49em;
}

.header-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  height: 49em;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-left: .5em;
}

.nav-header {
  grid-column: 2;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* Banner */

.slogan,
.banner {
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-image {
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
section.main-banner {
 position:  absolute;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
    top: 50%;
    left:  50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.sloganWrapper{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:  middle;

}

img.banner-image.banner {
    vertical-align:  middle;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
.sloganWrapper{
display:block;
}
}
```

```html
<!-- HEADER -->

<header class="header-image">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <h1 class="logo">STARTUP NAME</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-header">
        <li class="navmenu">Services</li>
        <li class="navmenu">Pricing</li>
        <li class="navmenu">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>


<!-- BANNER -->


<section class="main-banner">
  <div class="banner-container">
<div class="sloganWrapper">
    <h1 class="slogan banner">Some Cool Slogan</h1>
    <span class="slogan banner">A cool subtitle explaining said cool Slogan</span></div>
    <img class="banner-image banner" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532007271951-c487760934ae?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=f7ad947fb913065733cd1494ed95ef59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @RJorns Check the updated answer, This handled CSS below 767px also

Comment: @RJorns does it helped?

Comment: I just tried it and it actually moves the "slogan" and picture BEFORE it reaches 768px. It moves them out of center position. I am using Chrome Inspector, and it works fine for mobile Small-Large, but once you get to tablet and larger it moves them out of center position.

Comment: @RJorns i updated the code. Could you please check now

Comment: Excellent that worked! Thanks! I struggle with responsive design and specifically thinking mobile first in my HTML mark-up. That is a big help thanks!

Comment: @RJorns Happy learning! if it helped, upvote and accept the answer, so it will be helpful for others who look for similar issues..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your `.main-banner` is not being contained in the header.

Try making header `position: absolute;` and then move the banner image to `.main-banner`

See if it's what you need...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}


/* Header */

.header-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-left: .5em;
}

.nav-header {
  grid-column: 2;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* Banner */

.main-banner {
  padding-top: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472376758045-62f519fc676d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8300925c51f6d651fa7cb9c41eaafb45&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2850&q=80');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 49em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.slogan,
.banner {
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-image {
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- HEADER -->

<header>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <h1 class="logo">STARTUP NAME</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-header">
        <li class="navmenu">Services</li>
        <li class="navmenu">Pricing</li>
        <li class="navmenu">Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>


<!-- BANNER -->


<section class="main-banner">
  <div class="banner-container">
    <h1 class="slogan banner">Some Cool Slogan</h1>
    <span class="slogan banner">A cool subtitle explaining said cool Slogan</span>
    <img class="banner-image banner" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532007271951-c487760934ae?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=f7ad947fb913065733cd1494ed95ef59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
</section>

Testing
```

Comment: Alright, are you saying I need to add the banner image via CSS into the .main-banner element instead of using a img tag in HTML?

Comment: You can use `<img>` tag to present the banner picture as well but it should be inside the `.main-banner` instead of inside the `header`.

Comment: Ah excellent yes thanks I got that working, I put it all in the header section. Now I need to get it to be responsive. How can I get the "slogan" and image to stack on top of each other and have them be centered when I reach below 768px?